# Why is my Firebase Database not responding?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Authentication is working. Inside my code, if the authentication succeeds, I attempt to create a new user inside the Firebase Realtime Database with the following code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(UID).updateValues(with: dictionaryOfValues, completion: { ... print("Done.") ... })
```

This does absolutely nothing, though, and the Firebase Database remains empty.

I am not using CocoaPods, I opted to download the Firebase SDK and import the required Frameworks. I should point out that I cannot import the 'Firebase' framework. Instead, I included the firebase.h header file and imported the 'Firebase Auth' and 'Firebase Database' frameworks.

Here is the relevant code.

```
     @IBAction func signupButtonResponse(_ sender: Any) {
          Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: "test9@jonah.com", password: "ihateevilpeople") {
               (authDataResult, error) in
               if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
               }
               if let authData = authDataResult {
                    print(authData.user.email)
                    let dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                         "uid": authData.user.uid,
                         "email": authData.user.email,
                         "profileImageURL": "",
                         "status": ""
                    ]
                    print("About to attempt accessing the database...")
// NEW CODE //

                    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(authData.user.uid).updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {
                         (error, ref) in
                         if error == nil {
                              print("Done.")
                         }
                         else if error != nil {
                              print("xxxx")
                              print(error!.localizedDescription)
                              }
                    })
               }
          }
     }
```

EDIT - I added the following code to my project at NEW CODE:

```
                    let reference = Database.database().reference()

                    if reference != nil {
                         print("There is a database")
                    } else {
                         print("There is no database... \(reference)...")
                    }
```

And the console prints that there is no database.

If it makes a difference, I was not sure how to add the -ObjC linker flag as recommended on the Firebase website, so I did not add it.

Also, on the Firebase Database website, under "Usage", it says that 162.1 KB has been downloaded from the database... ?

Comment: Does your completion handler for the `updateChildValues()` method get called? If so, what does it print?

Comment: No it does not... not even an error. @FrankvanPuffelen ...I now check to see if the reference is nil, and it still says that there is no database (reference). I just checked to make sure that all of the frameworks required by the Firebase README file are loaded...

Comment: Next test: if you put a breakpoint on `if error == nil {` and run the code in a debugger, does it hit the breakpoint? And just to be certain, if you also put a breakpoint on `Database.database().reference().child("users")...`, does that one get hit in the debugger?

Comment: I appreciate the help... The break point on `if error == nil` does not get hit, but the other breakpoint does get hit. I have my rules on the Firebase Database website set so that `.read` and `.write` are both set to `true` ... I saw the YouTube tutorial of the SanFrancisco application that uses the RealTime Database... Except for the fact that I did not use pods, I can't think of anything that might be messing up this project. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: If the line that writes the data gets hit, the SDK seems to have loaded correctly. The most common reason for a write not making it through without the callback hitting, is when you have no internet connection on the device.

Comment: Hmmmm... is there anything else that could be problematic? I have been scouring the web and I think I read somewhere that the database might only be available on a WIFI connection and not a Mobile Connection.... ? I am running my project on my iPhone using a Mobile Connection that is simultaneously providing a hotspot via USB to my computer, which has the Firebase Console open. Also, if the SDK loaded correctly, shouldn't the reference to `Database.database().reference()` be returning a non-nil value? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I just updated the question to reflect the latest code, which still indicates that there is no reference... @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Also... I placed the breakpoint on the exact line that `Database.database().reference()...` gets called. If the breakpoint was struck, doesn't that just mean that the program began to execute that line? I am pretty sure that that would not mean that the Database was ever created... @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: You've omitted a few items that would help; there is required code in your AppDelegate that should be included as well as how you are initializing your Firebase; e.g. FirebaseApp.configure(). Also, there's probably no reason NOT to use CocoaPods - it just makes life easier setting up Firebase projects. Can you update your question with more complete code (as snippets please) of the important initialization? Also, you can't create users/write nodes so what do your Rules look like?

Comment: @Jay I got it to work. I just had to put all of the Firebase SDK frameworks into a folder that I then added to the project's Build Phases "Header Search Paths" directory list.